# java- field.set(objec1,object2) works only if the object1 is a string

Tags: java, field

I am new in java. I am trying to fill up a class from fields in a XML file. I made this code that looks as working but only with string fields

the code:

```
private void setValue(String className,  Node n, Object thObject) {

    try {

         Class oClass = thObject.getClass();
        Field [] f =  thObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < f.length; i++){
            if  (f[i].getName() == n.getNodeName()){
                    f[i].setAccessible(true);
                    try {
                        Object value = n.getNodeValue();
                        if (value != null) {
                            f[i].set(thObject, value);
                        }
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    }
                }
            }

    }
```

the `f[i].set` works only if it is a string field

I tried by doing :

```
f[i].setInt(thObject, Integer.parseInt(value.toString()))
```

but did not work the field says empty.

does anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: what is your class definition? it is not good idea for a newbie to use Java Reflection.

Comment: `if  (f[i].getName() == n.getNodeName()){` <= instead of `==` operator you should use `equals()` method

Comment: I am rewriting my program and I have the same idea in c# that I did a few years ago and it never made me problems, in java it is more problematic?

Answer (score 1):

Using Field.set() will not change the data type to suit the field type.  If you want to set a variety of types, you have to convert them first. e.g.

```
Field field = thObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(n.getNodeName());
field.setAccessible(true);
Object value = n.getNodeValue();
Object asType = convertToType(value, field.getType());
field.set(thObject, asType);
```

you have to implement convertToType to suit your needs.

---

here is a simple implementation.

```
private static final Map<Class, Class> WRAPPER_MAP = new LinkedHashMap<Class, Class>() {{
    put(boolean.class, Boolean.class);
    put(byte.class, Byte.class);
    put(char.class, Character.class);
    put(short.class, Short.class);
    put(int.class, Integer.class);
    put(float.class, Float.class);
    put(long.class, Long.class);
    put(double.class, Double.class);
}};

public static <T> T convertToType(Object o, Class<T> clazz) {
    Class<T> wrapper = WRAPPER_MAP.get(clazz);
    if (wrapper != null)
        clazz = wrapper;
    if (o == null || clazz.isInstance(o))
        return (T) o;
    try {
        try {
            Method valueOf = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("valueOf", o.getClass());
            return (T) valueOf.invoke(null, o);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
            Constructor<T> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(o.getClass());
            return constructor.newInstance(o);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    String text = "1000";
    for (Class clazz : new Class[]{String.class, Integer.class, double.class, BigDecimal.class, Thread.class}) {
        Object o = convertToType(text, clazz);
        System.out.println(o.getClass() + " " + o);
    }

    Object o = convertToType("RUNNABLE", Thread.State.class);
    System.out.println(o.getClass() + " " + o);

    String dateString = new Date().toString();
    Date date = convertToType(dateString, Date.class);
    System.out.println(date.getClass() + " " + date);
}
```

prints

```
class java.lang.String 1000
class java.lang.Integer 1000
class java.lang.Double 1000.0
class java.math.BigDecimal 1000
class java.lang.Thread Thread[1000,5,main]
class java.lang.Thread$State RUNNABLE
class java.util.Date Thu Jan 03 17:08:50 GMT 2013
```

The date string has to be a [format Date will parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29), or youc an use SimpleDateFormat to use a format of your choice.

Comment: why is this not working? f[i].setInt(thObject, Integer.parseInt(value.toString()))

Comment: `but did not work the field says empty.` is most likely because you used `==` instead of `equals` to compare the names of the fields.  If you just lookup the name as I did you don't need to perform this search.

Comment: Thanks!!! worked very good only Date I dont know how to do, can you help me with Date too?

Comment: @stlip You have to use a Date format Date supports.  Otherwise you have to parse the date yourself using SimpleDateFormat for your choice of format.

Comment: Thank you so much I realy appraised your help and the sample code that was realy helpfull

Answer (score 1):

Since the `Node#getNodeValue()` method return a String, you can only set that value on a field of type String. For other field types, you must convert the node value from a String to whatever the target field type is. You can inspect the field to get its type and take it from there.

Tough job for someone new to java. Good Luck!